# microsoft flow null required parameter

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I'm trying to create a custom connector in MS Flow but one of the required parameters is always null. I don't know why that's just how this web api is...

"&scope&catid=MFR"

I need to have the "scope" query parameter required show it shows up in the request but I need it to be a null value? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are connecting to, but different systems will interpret your parameters differently depending on what they expect. You could try "&scope=&catid=MFR" or if you can URL Encode it, try "%26scope%3D%00%26catid%3DMFR" which explicitly passes a Null.